# Unrecognized expression $dateDiff error in $addFields aggregator operator

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am facing this error on the provided code snippet below. Can someone help.

```
 > MongoError: Invalid $addFields :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$dateDiff'                       │
│                                                ││ index >     at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/backend/polygame_backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/conn  │
│                                                ││ index >     at Connection.emit (node:events:513:28)                                                              │
│                                                ││ index >     at Connection.emit (node:domain:489:12)                                                              │
│                                                ││ index >     at processMessage (/home/ubuntu/backend/polygame_backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/c  │
│                                                ││ index >     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/backend/polygame_backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connecti  │
│                                                ││ index >     at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)                                                                  │
│                                                ││ index >     at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)                                                                  │
│                                                ││ index >     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)                                                  │
│                                                ││ index >     at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)                                           │
│                                                ││ index >     at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)                                      │
│                                                ││ index >     at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)                                       │
│                                                ││ index >     at TCP.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {                                       │
│                                                ││ index >   ok: 0,                                                                                                 │
│                                                ││ index >   code: 168,                                                                                             │
│                                                ││ index >   codeName: 'InvalidPipelineOperator'                                                                    │
│                                                ││ index > }  

Code

            $addFields: {
          apy: "$stakeplan.apy",
          days: {
            $dateDiff: {
              startDate: "$createdAt",
              endDate: new Date("Thu, 17 Nov 2022 17:56:42 GMT"),
              unit: "day",
            },
          },
        },
```

Comment: What is your mongoDB version? `$dateDiff` was introduced on version 5.0...